# Fragment in activity startup taking more time than expected

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am a beginner-intermediate android developer. I started working with fragments in my this app. The structure of the app is:

1. Main activity where some important links are embedded with buttons
2. On clicking button from main activity, some DB tasks completed (with Room Library so all tasks are using AsyncTask) and new activity opens with link in intent extra
3. On getting the link, the new activity-2 adds a fragment (in itself) and also performs some DB tasks in background and then opens the link in webview of fragment.

The problem is, from 1-2 it is taking merely 0.1-0.15 seconds while on starting the task 3, it is taking 0.3-0.45 seconds so on clicking from main activity, user is getting the link opened in fragment (which has webview) in about 0.6 seconds which is making feel like app is freezing.

Here are some codes:
Activity-2:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    prefSingleton = PrefSingleton.getInstance();
    if (prefSingleton.getStorage().getBoolean(Constants.STORAGE_ENABLE_NIGHTMODE,false)){
        setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_website_view);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    closeWebview = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.closeWebview);
    downArrow = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.downArrow);
    allTabs = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.allTabs);
    searchIcon = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.search);
    clearEditText = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.clearEditText);
    selectedSEImage = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.selectedSEImage);
    searchEditText = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);
    searchEngineFrame = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.searchEngine);
    searchBarLayout = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.searchBarLayout);
    toolbarTitle = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolBarTitle);
    navFrame = findViewById(R.id.navFrame);
    navRecView = findViewById(R.id.navRecView);

    if (prefSingleton.getStorage().getBoolean(Constants.STORAGE_ENABLE_NIGHTMODE,false)){
        navFrame.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.night_mode_toolbar));
    }

    //Activity toolbar views
    closeWebview.setOnClickListener(this);
    closeWebview.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    downArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
    allTabs.setOnClickListener(this);
    searchIcon.setOnClickListener(this);
    clearEditText.setOnClickListener(this);
    searchEngineFrame.setOnClickListener(this);
    searchEditText.setOnClickListener(this);
    searchEditText.setOnKeyListener(this);

    //Intent from main activity
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String urlType = i.getStringExtra(String.valueOf(EnumVal.SiteInfoToSend.TYPE));
    final String url = i.getStringExtra(String.valueOf(EnumVal.SiteInfoToSend.URL));
    String title = i.getStringExtra(String.valueOf(EnumVal.SiteInfoToSend.TITLE));
    String searchedText = i.getStringExtra(String.valueOf(EnumVal.SiteInfoToSend.SEARCHED_TEXT));

    fragCounter = 0;
    fragTags = new ArrayList<>();

    //Fragment opening
    if (savedInstanceState == null){
        openFragment(url, EnumVal.FragStatus.NEW, null);
    }

    //AdMob Ads
    if (!BuildConfig.PAID_VERSION){
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.interstitial_webview));
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                if(ConsentInformation.getInstance(WebsiteView.this).getConsentStatus() ==
                        ConsentStatus.NON_PERSONALIZED){
                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putString("npa", "1");
                    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
                            .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class,extras).build());
                } else {
                    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                }
            }
        });
        if(ConsentInformation.getInstance(WebsiteView.this).getConsentStatus() == ConsentStatus.NON_PERSONALIZED){
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("npa", "1");
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class,extras).build());
        } else {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    }

    //Toolbar search edit text will be enabled in below case
    if (urlType.equals(EnumVal.Type.SEARCHED_TEXT.toString())){
        searchBarLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        searchIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.close_icon);
        searchEditText.setText(searchedText);
        searchEditText.clearFocus();
        searchEditText.setCursorVisible(false);
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        if (searchEditText.hasFocus())
            searchEditText.setCursorVisible(true);

    }


    searchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            clearEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    //Navigation view in toolbar
    navRecView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DbViewModel.class);
    mViewModel.getSitesWithClicksByIsShown().observe(this, new Observer<List<SitesWithClicks>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<SitesWithClicks> sitesWithClicks) {
            if (sitesWithClicks!= null && sitesWithClicks.size()>0){
                int reArrSite = prefSingleton.getStorage().getInt(Constants.STORAGE_REARRANGESITE_NAV,
                        Constants.SORTING_PRIORITY);

                sitesWithClicks = Utility.sortSitesData(reArrSite, sitesWithClicks);
                navAdapter = new ListRecViewAdapter(EnumVal.DialogType.NAVBAR_ITEMS,
                        sitesWithClicks, WebsiteView.this);
                navRecView.setAdapter(navAdapter);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Open-fragment method:

```
public void openFragment(String url, EnumVal.FragStatus fragStatus, String toOpenTag){
    if(navFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
        downArrow.performClick();

    if(fragStatus == EnumVal.FragStatus.NEW){
        String fragTag = getNextFragTag();

        WebsiteViewFragment fragment = WebsiteViewFragment.newInstance(url, fragTag);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if(fragCounter == 1){
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment, fragTag);
            currentFrag = fragTag;
        } else {
            if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(currentFrag) != null){
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
                fragmentTransaction.hide(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(currentFrag));
            }

            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment, fragment, fragTag);
            currentFrag = fragTag;
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        fragTags.add(new TabDetail(fragTag,"Tab - 1",null));

    } else if (fragStatus == EnumVal.FragStatus.OLD){
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(currentFrag) != null){
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(currentFrag));
        }

        fragmentTransaction.show(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(toOpenTag));
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        currentFrag = toOpenTag;
    }
}
```

And Fragment has just Webview in it where webview is loading lot of websettings. But thing is reaching till fragment is taking time ,like user clicks from main activity and after about 0.6 seconds, fragment is opening while activity which has fragment is taking just 0.1 second to open so this time is (maybe) related to attaching fragment or something?

Can anyone please explain me, where am I making mistake?

I had some doubt regarding this:

1. Is the problem webview (in fragment), which has a bunch of websettings ?
2. Is attaching fragment to activity-2 taking more time?
3. Is UI part of activity-2 taking time (like toolbar setup which has 4 buttons) and after that fragment is attaching to it, which is resulting in more time consumption ?
4. Or it is a normal situation ?

Can someone, please, explain me the way to make it to <0.2 seconds for whole tasks? Thanks in advance.

Comment: without seeing any code the only thing I can suggest is that you comment out everything that is being loaded in the activities and fragments that have a long delay. While debugging simply start adding code bits to see where the delays are.

Comment: Should I post the codes? it is a bit longer. And I tried the way you are suggesting, it's not helping much. @Barns

Comment: Try to keep the code you post as succinct as possible, but posting some of the code would certainly be helpful. seeing how the data is gathered from the BG thread and then presented would be a good start. And it would be good to know if there are a lot of views in the Fragments.

Comment: I have posted the codes @Barns. Can you please check?

Comment: @Barns Fragment has just webview and lot of websettings, nothing else.

Comment: can i've a look at your code?

Comment: You really have a lot going on in your `onCreate()` method. All the views you are referencing, the AdMob and triggering the fragment. That is a lot to do in the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: You should profile your code first with the CPU Profiler so that you actually know what takes such a long time.

Comment: @Barns so what is the best way if I've to initialize all the views only once and have to reference views as soon as page displays. If I'd define it in onResume() then it will get called Everytime app will come back from onPause or so. Please explain.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I'll try this way and will update further